# what is the good book for learning vim?

Tags: vimrc

I have been use vim since 1 year. But I don't know about all facilities in vim, although I know that vim is powerful text editor.

So, I want to learn vim in a sequential way by reading a book.

I use vim in terminal on Ubuntu 14.04 and on Fedora 25.

Thanks for response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A Byte of Vim](http://www.swaroopch.com/notes/vim/)

[The vim book](ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/doc/book/vimbook-OPL.pdf)

[Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/)

[O’Reilly’s Learning the vi and Vim Editors](ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/doc/book/vimbook-OPL.pdf)

recommended books in http://vim.begin-site.org/books/

You can also read *Practical vim* by *Drew Neil*